# Download pdf with large records

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am using dompdf in laravel for generating pdf of large records, but it is taking more than 3 minutes to download.
Although I have tried many solutions like :

1. Remove all CSS and external links also there is no inline CSS only simple HTML table.
2. The query is working fine and executing in milliseconds.
3. I have increased the ini_memory limit too but didn't work.

Need to download around 3K-4K records.

Comment: Is the width of your table columns fixed, or are you letting them size dynamically based on the content? The latter makes the rendering process at lot more complex in HTML already, and transforming that to PDF probably has similar issues.

Comment: The table columns are dynamic, based on the content.

Comment: @all why there is downvote to the question if you dont know the answer that does not mean question is wrong.

Comment: Which version of PHP and Dompdf are you using. More recent versions of PHP have significant performance improvements. Also, can't really help with optimizing the Dompdf aspect without seeing a sample of the HTML + CSS.